# How to remove white border and table cell space of table in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am studying iOS with the book "Beginning iOS9 Programming with Swift" and there is an exercise about Table Views. I created the project step by step according to steps in the book. The page what got is :

[image]

There is a spacing between each table cell, and the width of the table is not 100% of the simulator. How can I make it better?

I want to get a page like this :

[image]

Comment: remove the table view separator. Make the width of table view to the screen width. `self.tableview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None`

Comment: Please share some code.

Answer (score 0):

The lines that appear under each cell are called "separator lines", you can remove them by selecting "separator style" to "none" in the attributes inspector. 
see Image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnGLU.png

To remove the white space, you have to cover the whole superView i.e cover the whole cell of the tableview with your image.
Currently it is like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp5mX.png

Answer (score 0):

Thank @Rohan Lokesh Sharma. But I found out my mistakes. I need to uncheck the "Constrain to margins" before add constraints.

Selecting "separator style" to "none" will remove grey lines between every cell but the "white space" is still showing.